# How can I place two circuit diagrams next to each other?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, circuitikz

I made these two circuit diagrams:
[image]

But I don't want them to be one above the other, instead I want them to be ''in the same line'' if that makes sense, one next to the other. I tried the multicolumn thing and it didn't work as it should.

Circuit code:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B, 7/0/C, 11/0/D, 14/0/E, 14/4/F, 11/4/G, 7/4/H, 3/4/I, 0/4/J}
    
    \draw (A) to[short] (B);
    
    \draw (J) to[R, l=$R$] (I);
    
    \draw (A) to[european resistor, l_=$\Bar{Z_{a}}$, v^<=$v_a$] (J);
    
    \draw (B) to[sV] (I);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B, 7/0/C, 11/0/D, 14/0/E, 14/4/F, 11/4/G, 7/4/H, 3/4/I, 0/4/J}
    
    \draw (A) to[short, -*] (B) to[short] (C);
    
    \draw (J) to[short, -*] (I) to[R, l=$R$] (H);
    
    \draw (A) to[R, l_=$R_a$, v^<=$v_a$] (J);
    
    \draw (C) to[sV] (H);
    
    \draw (B) to[cute inductor, l_=$L$] (I);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why you define those nodes that you won't use them. Those will create empty space in your figure. I have deleted them.

And notice: If next time you ask a question, please provide a minimum work example. (as the code in my answer that someone can compile it without guessing which packages and document class you are using)

Here is the solution in standalone class. It should work in other document class:

```
\documentclass[border=0.618cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B, 3/4/I, 0/4/J}
    
\draw (A) to[short] (B);
    
\draw (J) to[R, l=$R$] (I);
    
\draw (A) to[european resistor, l_=$\Bar{Z_{a}}$, v^<=$v_a$] (J);
    
\draw (B) to[sV] (I);

\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B, 7/0/C, 7/4/H, 3/4/I, 0/4/J}
    
\draw (A) to[short, -*] (B) to[short] (C);
    
\draw (J) to[short, -*] (I) to[R, l=$R$] (H);
    
\draw (A) to[R, l_=$R_a$, v^<=$v_a$] (J);
    
\draw (C) to[sV] (H);
    
\draw (B) to[cute inductor, l_=$L$] (I);
\end{scope}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As Tom said before, please always provide a minimal working example (MWE).

Your problem is pretty simple. You have a blank line here:

```
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
```

That creates a new paragraph. Once you delete that blank line, it looks like this:

[image: circuit]

Comment: You are right. This is a neat solution. But I still think if two diagrams next to each other should be drawn in the same tikz picture. I guess it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Tom I just added this solution for making him understand the root cause. Your solution is more tikz of course.

Comment: thank you both! it was, indeed, real helpful. and yeah, it doesn't matter in this case, so glad it worked :)

Comment: @ronny Please mark Tom's answer as solution, since it is the better solution. Mine is more correct in this context, but his solution will help future internet searchers more than mine.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz I am not sure --- often having small circuits to compose in figures is the best solution. Clearly, it depends on semantics; if you have a single circuit with two parts, use a single environment; otherwise, if circuits are different, use different environments.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz additionally, notice that you can choose easily *where* to align vertically the circuits, by saying `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A)] ...` and  `\begin{tikzpicture}[align=(H)]...`  (or whatever you need).